# How to apply custom font to TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, tttattributedlabel

I am using [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) in my project . And am trying to apply custom font for that label .

```
#define DEFAULT_FONT(s)     [UIFont fontWithName:MY_FONT_NAME size:s]
```

I used the below code to set font :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) TTTAttributedLabel *welcomeMessage;

NSString *welcomeMessageString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.dashboardViewModel getWelcomeMessage]] uppercaseString];
    [self.welcomeMessage setText:welcomeMessageString afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString){
        NSRange boldRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"Welcome " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        NSRange colorRange = NSMakeRange((boldRange.location + boldRange.length), (welcomeMessageString.length - boldRange.length));
        UIFont *systemBoldFont = DEFAULT_FONT(13);
        CTFontRef boldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)systemBoldFont.fontName, systemBoldFont.pointSize, NULL);
        if (boldFont) {
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)RGB(134.0, 0, 0).CGColor range:colorRange];
            CFRelease(boldFont);

        }


        return mutableAttributedString;
    }];
    self.welcomeMessage.font = DEFAULT_FONT(13);
```

But in my app am font is not getting applied .  I need "Welcome" text in black color and remaining part of the text to be in red color .  But for my label  i need to apply the my custom font .

Comment: Did you added the font name in info.plist file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 CTFontRef boldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)systemBoldFont.fontName, systemBoldFont.pointSize, NULL);
    if (boldFont) {
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)boldFont range:nameRange];
        CFRelease(boldFont);

    }
```

Comment: i need to add font color for particular range . But i want the font to applied to label

Comment: @Vinodh in your code does the color worked or both font and color not working?

Comment: You can set font by above code, and you can add the code for color with this

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
if (boldFont) {
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)RGB(134.0, 0, 0).CGColor range:colorRange];
    CFRelease(boldFont);
}
```

you are checking `boldFont` and then add a color. Is it correct? If you need o add a font use `kCTFontAttributeName` key.